# php nested query in laravel using query builder

Tags: php, json, laravel

[image]I am making ecommerce app api using laravel and have 1 table for product data and another table for product images

This query works fine. I want nested query in which each product will have its list of images.I am making android app and need to show multiple product images in carousel slider and need to get nested JSON

```
$products = DB::table('products')->where ('stock_quantity',  '<>' , 0 )->inRandomOrder()->get();
```

in products table I have unique 'id' and and same id is used in product_images table to map data.

[image]

Comment: Why not using eloquent ?

Comment: you should add table/model relations between product and product images, eg `hasMany` and `belongsTo` then fetch the products `with(images)`. In general outline

Comment: @NikosM. : He is using query builder not eloquent/model

Comment: i have read in few articles that eloquent is slow compared query builder. Also, I need to filter product where stock <> 0, which i am not sure in eloquent model.

Answer (score 1):

i think simple [join](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins) will do the purpose:

```
 $products = DB::table('products')->where ('stock_quantity',  '<>' , 0 )->join('product_images',
            'product_images.product_id','products.id')->select('product.*','product_images*')
            ->get();
```

however, i must say that i don't recommend this kind of storing images, you should store a product_image for each row, not 7 product image for each row ....

Comment: I am able to use joinSub and get all 7 images. what i need is those 7 images to nested . joinSub query  `$products = DB::table('products')->where ('stock_quantity',  '<>' , 0 )->inRandomOrder()
 //          ->joinSub($product_images = DB::table('product_images'), 'product_images', function ($join) {$join->on('products.id', '=', 'product_images.product_id');})->get();`

Comment: if you want those images to be nested you should rebuild tables schema and build eloquent models